# multiple scanf in a program causing crash in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{       
    printf("how old are you? ");
    int age = 0;
    scanf("%d", age);

    printf("how much does your daily habit cost per day? \n");
    int daily = 0;
    scanf("%d", daily); 

    double thisyear = daily * 365;

    printf("\n");
    printf("this year your habit will cost you: %.2f", thisyear);

    return 0;
}
```

this is my program for school, when i write this i am trying get the user to 1, give their age and 2, their daily cost of living. however my program would crash when i run this

Comment: for the second part it supppose to be
printf("how much does your daily habit cost per day? \n");
float daily = 0;
scanf("%.2f", daily);

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html

Answer (score 3):

<strike>scanf("%d", daily);</strike>

needs to become

```
scanf("%d", &daily);
```

You need to pass the address of the variable (i.e., a pointer, this is done with the `&`) to `scanf` so that the value of the variable can be changed.  The same applies for your other prompt. Change it to

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

Now you should get this when you run your program:

```
% a.out
how old are you? 30
how much does your daily habit cost per day? 
20

this year your habit will cost you: 7300.00
```

Comment: ahh thanks you however when i run the program now it gives me 0.00

Comment: @TianyouHu I just ran the corrected version and it worked. Can you tell me more about the problem and how you are getting 0.00?

Comment: @TianyouHu If this answer helped you with your problem/question, please feel free to accept it - this will give you and me some reputation points and mark this question as solved. You can do this by clicking the checkmark next to my answer - or see this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1):

The scanf function expects a pointer.

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

Ditto for the line where you scanf on "daily".

Comment: -1 your space before "%d" is redundant, a single "%d" will **ever** ignore all heading whitespaces before any integer literal in input stream

Comment: @user411313 - Hmmm... I seem to recall that fixing a common bug, but it escapes me now. I'll just remove that from the answer until I can recall why... might have to dig up a book.

Comment: @user411313 - It's quoted in this book to do as such.  ( http://www.amazon.com/C-Example-Greg-Perry/dp/0789722399/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1338705794&sr=1-2 ) But for the life of me, I can't seem to recall or reproduce the common bug that the leading space in the scanf control helps mitigate. Something to do with trailing or leading whitespace in input.  Might allow for leading whitespace when reading character by character at a time with %c. I'll just email the author if I can track him down!

Answer (score 0):

scanf works with references to variables

```
printf("how old are you? ");
int age = 0;
scanf("%d", &age);

printf("how much does your daily habit cost per day? \n");
int daily = 0;
scanf("%d", &daily); 

double thisyear = daily * 365;

printf("\n");
printf("this year your habit will cost you: %.2f", thisyear);
```